# Equivalent condition for complex differentiability

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, derivatives, continuity

Let the standard definition for complex differentiability at $a \in D \subset \Bbb{C}$ of a function $f : D \to \Bbb{C}$ be that the limit

$$
\lim\limits_{z \to a} \dfrac{f(z) - f(a)}{z - a}
$$

exists and equals $l \in \Bbb{C}$.

This is equivalent to the condition:

> There exists a function $\varphi : D \to \Bbb{C}$ which is continuous at $a$ such that $f(z) = f(a) + \varphi(z)(z - a)$ and $\varphi(a) = l$.

Since $a$ is a point of accumulation of $D$ define $\varphi(z) = \dfrac{f(z) - f(a)}{z - a}, \ \varphi : D \to \Bbb{C}$ except at $a$ where we define $\varphi(a) = l$.  How do I prove that $\varphi(z)$ is continuous?  Since I don't know whether $f$ is yet (that's part of a corollary to this list of equivalent conditions).

Comment: Since $l= \lim_{z\to a} \varphi (z)$, is continuity of $\varphi$ at $a$ not true by construction? Note that the condition you have only requires continuity at $a$. Or do you require continuity of $\varphi$ on $D$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have been give that the value of $\phi(a)=l$. Now you need to show that the limit as $z$ approaches $a$ of the function $\phi$ is indeed $l$, but this is obvious since 
$$
\lim_{z\to a}\phi(z)=\lim_{z\to a}\frac{f(z)-f(a)}{z-a}=f'(a)=l
$$
by assumption.